# Danted starts without error but not working

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

I installed danted on ubuntu 22.04.1 with apt package manager and everything worked find 'till I tried to connect to it.

this my `/etc/danted.conf`

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: ens160 port = 110
external: ens160
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: username
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        command: bind connect udpassociate
        log: error connect disconnect
        socksmethod: username
}
socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

and this is `systemctl status danted.service` output:

```
● danted.service - SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/danted.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-09-28 10:08:31 +0330; 5min ago
       Docs: man:danted(8)
             man:danted.conf(5)
    Process: 7117 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c       uid=`sed -n -e "s/[[:space:]]//g" -e "s/#.*//" -e "/^user\.privileged/{s/[^:]*://p;q;}" /etc/danted.conf`;      if [ -n "$uid" ]; then          touch /var/run/danted.pid;          chown $uid /var/run/danted.pid;     fi       (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 7121 (danted)
      Tasks: 20 (limit: 1030)
     Memory: 7.3M
        CPU: 647ms
        ⠇
```

`netstat -tulp` output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 static.<server-ip backward without the first three digits>:pop3 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7121/danted         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1034/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 ubuntu20:pop3           [::]:*                  LISTEN      7121/danted         
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1034/sshd: /usr/sbi 
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                           838/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 localhost:snmp          0.0.0.0:*                           847/snmpd           
udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:snmp      [::]:*                              847/snmpd
```

but when I try running curl `curl -x socks5://danteduser:<user pass>@<my server ip address>:110 google.com`, I get this:
`curl: (97) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response.`

`journalctl -l | grep danted` outoput (for last `systemctl restart danted`):

```
Sep 28 10:08:31 ubuntu20 systemd[1]: Stopping SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Sep 28 10:08:31 ubuntu20 systemd[1]: danted.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 28 10:08:31 ubuntu20 systemd[1]: Stopped SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
Sep 28 10:08:31 ubuntu20 systemd[1]: Starting SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Sep 28 10:08:31 ubuntu20 systemd[1]: Started SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
```

Apparently port 110 is not even open, When I try `telnet <server ip> 110` on my local machine, I get this:

```
Trying <server ip>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

This is `/var/log/socks.log` file content after starting the service:

```
Sep 28 11:58:44 (1664353724.536076) danted[8351]: info: Dante/server[1/1] v1.4.2 running
```

no new log in this file after sending curl request!

Comment: Your configuration is working for me. Anything in the log file on the server?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider No, It can't open `/var/log/socks.log` for writing, but I added `journalctl -l | grep danted` output for last service restart to the question.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider fixed the `Read-only file system` warning but everything seems ok in log file.